# MySQL concate 1 column from many records

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have table , table_A:

| Transnumber | lpost |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | 0 |
| A002 | 1 |
| A003 | 1 |
| A004 | 1 |
| A005 | 0 |
| A006 | 1 |

I need to store transnumbers in one variable, with condition lpost=0
In MsSQl Server I can use :

```
SELECT @var1=@var1+','+rtrim(table_A.Transnumber) FROM table_A where lpost=0
```

In MySQL I try :

```
Set @var1='';
Select concat(@var1,'-',Transnumber) into @var1 FROM table_A where lpost=0 ;
```

It doesn't work

How the right syntax in MySQL?
The result I expect : `@var1 = A001,A005`

Comment: What should be the output from `@var1` ... something like `0-A005` or some other format?

Comment: I need result :
A001,A005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` to help.

Consider:

```
set @var1 = (select group_concat(transnumber) from table_A where lpost = 0);
```

Then afterwards:

```
select @var1;
```

Gives:

[image]

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ujiGAy8r) with that example.

---

Edit:

As `Akina` pointed out, the `SELECT ... INTO ...` format can be used as well.

So for an example with this syntax:

```
SET @var1 = '';
select group_concat(transnumber) into @var1 from table_A where lpost = 0;
```

Will give the same result. See this [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fQonW3cT) with this 2nd example added.

Comment: SELECT INTO is more correct than SET..

Comment: Thanks @Akina, I've update the answer (and the fiddle) to show example usage with that format.